# How to programatically change the margin of a canvas

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to programmatically change the margin of a canvas.I try the code  `listBox_Library.Margin = -3,35,0,0;` but it shows error.if any one knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Margin` is of type `Thickness`, see the [MSDN  documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx). Set it in code as follows:

```
listBox_Library.Margin = new Thickness(-3,35,0,0);
```